# Index position of randsample in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random

I'm using the randsample function of Matlab to sample a data point in the following way:

```
points = randi(100,1,10);
weighting_vector = rand(1,10);
normalized_weighting_vector = weighting_vector ./ sum(weighting_vector);
point = randsample(points,1,'true',normalized_weighting_vector);
```

How can I get the index of the selected point?

For example if points = [1,2,2,3,4,4,4,8,9,3] and point = 4, I would like to know the index position of the chosen value, which can either be 5, 6 or 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `randsample` on your data, randomly sample the *indices* and then convert these indices to their corresponding values in `points`.

```
points =  [1,2,2,3,4,4,4,8,9,3];

% Randomly choose N indices from the possible index values for points
index = randsample(1:numel(points), 1, true);

% Get the point corresponding to these indices
point = points(index)
```